# Slider in AnimatedList has wrong value

Tags: flutter, flutter-animatedlist, flutter-slider

I have a chat bubble widget which has a audio player support with a `Slider` widget.
The slider's value is changed according to the AudioPlayer's progress which seems to work fine.

When the first audio is played completely (meaning the slider's value is now 100%), & now the second chat bubble is added to the `AnimatedList` then the newest Slider has the value of 100 & the previous has the value of 0.

Here's an example to understand better:
Message 1 added to list: Audio Played completed => Slider value is 100.
Message 2 added to list: Slider value is 100 (should be 0) & the slider from message 1 has value of 0.

Here's the widget:

```dart
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MessageBubbleAudioPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  final String audioUrl;

  const MessageBubbleAudioPlayer({
    @required this.audioUrl,
    @required this.color,
  });

  @override
  _MessageBubbleAudioPlayerState createState() =>
      _MessageBubbleAudioPlayerState();
}

class _MessageBubbleAudioPlayerState extends State<MessageBubbleAudioPlayer> {
  bool loading = false;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  double audioSeekValue = 0;
  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  Duration totalDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((event) {
        if (mounted) setState(() => isPlaying = event == PlayerState.PLAYING);
      });

      audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((event) {
        final percent =
            ((event.inMilliseconds * 100) / totalDuration.inMilliseconds) ?? 0;
        if (mounted) setState(() => audioSeekValue = percent);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        loading
            ? Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: widget.color,
                  strokeWidth: 1.8,
                ),
              )
            : Container(
                width: 30,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: widget.color),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                      audioPlayer.resume();
                      return;
                    }

                    if (!isPlaying) {
                      setState(() => loading = true);
                      await audioPlayer.play(widget.audioUrl);
                      audioPlayer.getDuration().then((value) {
                        totalDuration = Duration(milliseconds: value);
                        setState(() => loading = false);
                      });
                    } else
                      await audioPlayer.pause();
                  },
                  splashRadius: 25,
                ),
              ),
        SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
              trackHeight: 1.4,
              thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 7)),
          child: Slider(
            label: "Audio",
            activeColor: widget.color,
            inactiveColor: widget.color.withAlpha(100),
            // this (value) should be 0 for a newly added widget 
            // but is 100 for the newer one & 0 for the previous one,
            // which infact should be opposite
            value: audioSeekValue,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            onChanged: (_) {},
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This widget is in turn used in another widget which handles the type of message & shows appropriate ui.
Here it is:

```dart
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSender, isAudio;
  final String message;

  const MessageBubble(this.message, this.isSender, this.isAudio, Key key)
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 3),
      child: Align(
          alignment: isSender ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: message.contains(Constants.emojiRegex, 0) &&
                  !message.contains(Constants.alphaNumericRegex)
              ? Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 6,
                      bottom: 6,
                      left: isSender ? 16 : 0,
                      right: isSender ? 0 : 32),
                  child: Text(message,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, color: Colors.white)),
                )
              : Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  elevation: 4,
                  color: isSender
                      ? Colors.deepPurpleAccent.shade100.darken()
                      : Colors.white,
                  child: isAudio
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20, vertical: 6),
                          child: MessageBubbleAudioPlayer(
                            key: ValueKey(message.hashCode.toString()),
                            audioUrl: message,
                            color: isSender
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                          ),
                        )
                      : Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 20, vertical: 14),
                          child: Linkify(
                            onOpen: (link) async {
                              if ((await canLaunch(link.url)))
                                await launch(link.url);
                            },
                            options: LinkifyOptions(humanize: false),
                            linkStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: isSender
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                            text: message,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17,
                                color: isSender ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                )),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the `AnimatedList`:

```dart
class ChatAnimatedList extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isInfoShown, isSender;

  const ChatAnimatedList(
      {@required Key key, @required this.isInfoShown, this.isSender})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  ChatAnimatedListState createState() => ChatAnimatedListState();
}

class ChatAnimatedListState extends State<ChatAnimatedList> {
  final _messageList = <MessageBubble>[];
  final _animatedListState = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  get messageLength => _messageList.length;

  insertMessageBubble(MessageBubble messageBubble) =>
      _messageList.insert(0, messageBubble);

  insertViaState() {
    if (_animatedListState.currentState != null)
      _animatedListState.currentState.insertItem(0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.isInfoShown
        ? InfoPlaceholder(isSender: widget.isSender)
        : Expanded(
            child: AnimatedList(
                reverse: true,
                key: _animatedListState,
                initialItemCount: _messageList.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index, animation) {
                  return index == 0
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                          child: _messageList[index])
                      : index == _messageList.length - 1
                          ? Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              child: _messageList[index])
                          : _messageList[index];
                }),
          );
  }
}
```

I've also tried using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but still no use.
Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This probably happening due to your Widgets being of the same type.

While flutter checks the changes in the widget tree, it checks for the `type` of the widget as well the `key` provided while creating that widget.

From you example, it is clear that no `key` is being provided while creating the `StatefulWidget`.

So, when you are pushing a new `Widget` (and I assume you are pushing this widget earlier than the old widget in the tree), flutter thinks this is still the older widget and assigns the older `State` object to it.

Start, sending a unique key whenever you are creating new `StatefulWidget`s that exist inside a `List` type widgets like `Row`, `Column` etc.,

```
class MessageBubbleAudioPlayer extends StatefulWidget {

  const MessageBubbleAudioPlayer({
    @required this.audioUrl,
    @required this.color,
    Key key.
  }) : super(key: key);
```

While creating a new one,

```
MessageBubbleAudioPlayer(audioUrl: '', color: '', key: ValueKey(#some unique int or string#)
```

In place of `#some unique int or string#` put something that is going to be unique to that widget, not an index since that can change, but you can use the `audioUrl` itself as a key.

Comment: This seems to work, but the state of the slider is set to `0` for all the items when a new item is added. Any idea how to preserve the values of existing ones?

Comment: Update your post with the code where you are using the `MessageBubbleAudioPlayer` widget, that might provide me some insight.

Comment: added the parent widget.

Comment: so you have some parent where you are adding multiple `MessageBubble`s ?

Comment: `MessageBubble` is a main widget which handles to show appropriate ui depending on the type of message (text or audio). This is the widget that gets added to the `AnimatedList`.

Comment: Ha, that's what I'm saying, your AnimatedList is the parent, could you post just that code as well

Comment: added that as well :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232798/discussion-between-nisanth-reddy-and-darshan).

Comment: I instead went ahead & created a value manager class that properly records and handles the value of new & old ones depending on the key values passed (keys are audioUrl), which is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

1. When your audio play is completed make **audioSeekValue = 0** . This will start from the begening.
2. If you want to keep track :
   Song 1 played = 70%
   Song 2 played = 50%

In this case, you have to either keep your index song played valued in a list or get the song played value dynamically from the backend.

Please let me know if it helps.